# Display a field in a view using comma separated values

Tags: 7, views

I have content type "test" which has fields title, uuid(text field with one value allowed)

In view I am using Unformatted List.

In view uuid values are displayed as below:

```
akjfkljdf
jkljljkjl 
kdjsfljksdlf
```

But I want the uuid values to be displayed as below:

```
akjfkljdf, jkljljkjl, kdjsfljksdlf
```

I tried to use template file named "views-view-field--test--field-uuid.tpl" and kept this template file in sites/all/modules/views/theme/ folder, but its not working . Template file has code:

```
 <?php print implode(",",$output); ?>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure about the code error, But if you take the uuid as multiple text field you will get comma separated output(as you want).

Comment: @Rama raju dantuluri: uuid is not a multiple text field. I want that to as text field with only one value only.

Comment: At first try to add the tpl file in the theme folder (which theme are you using?). I don't understand: on each row how many uuid values do you have?